# Running "rails s" causes help page to be printed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, rvm

I have never seen this weird issue before. I have a Rails 4.2.5 app on an EC2 instance. Ruby version is 2.3.1.

Everything bundled and installed fine, but when i run `rails s`, i end up getting the man-page of other flags to supply to `rails`

Straight from the terminal:

```
$ rails s
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/ubuntu/githubstars/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.

$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.5

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing your bin directory. Generate a new project somewhere and copy the bin folder over.

Comment: i inherited the project, and it turns out there were all these require/load that was interfering. Thanks!

Comment: You could also call `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin`.